# Ubuntu One files are downloaded but not available

Tags: ubuntu-one

after Purchasing some Music on the U1 Music Store the files were synced from u1 to the computer where I purchased the Albums (Ubuntu 11.04).

On a different machine (Ubuntu 11.10) only some Tracks are synced and showing up the rest is not there. `u1sdtool --current-transfers` Was listing some of the missing files. After watching this process for a long (very long) time the downloads finally finished and disappeared from the current-tranfers list.

But when i go to `~/.ubuntuone/Purchased From Ubuntu On/Artist/Album` the directory is present but empty.
Why the is u1 downloading half of a day and then not showing the files? Is there any temporary place where the files are stored before copying them to their target location?

Any Suggestions what could be the Problem?

Comment: I tried several tips I found throughout the internet. Nothing worked. Is there a way to reset the ubuntu one client? Delete all configs, caches etc ...

Comment: Deleting ~/.config/ubuntuone and ~/.local/share/ubuntuone should get all configs, settings, etc. cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suggested by Nathan Dyer I tried deleting the suggested config which did not work well.
I did some further research and found the following thread:

[Thread Posting on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8146023&postcount=2)

I followed steps 1 to 6 described there but modified the actions a bit.

1. Remove the Computer via the Ubuntu One Client
2. Quit Ubuntu One
3. Run `u1sdtool -q && killall ubuntuone-syncdaemon`
4. Remove ubuntu one stetting and cache as suggested by Nathan Dyer

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone ~/.cache/ubuntuone ~/.config/ubuntuone
   ```
5. Remove/Rename ubuntu on folder

   ```
   mv ~/Ubuntu\ One ~/old.u1
   ```
6. Remove all other folders that were synced with u1 including .ubuntuone

   ```
   rm -fr ~/.ubuntuone
   ```
7. Open Unity Dash and find the "Passwords and Encryption Keys" application. Go to the Passwords tab, delete all Couch DB and Ubuntu One tokens
8. Open the Ubuntu One client again and re-register the computer for sync

After going through all this U1 synced everything from scratch and it finally solved ma issues. I guess step 7 (removing all tokens) did the trick.

I hope this might help someone having the same problem.